# Using Switch Case with Radio Buttons and Appending Result to a List Box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am pretty new to programming and have a C# Assignment for school. I have been searching for a couple hours now and I can't find a similar case that seems to address what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a windows form with 5 radio buttons. My assignment is to create a sales calculator using a switch statement to determine which radio button has been selected and based on the radio button selected get a sales total by multiplying the quantity of items sold by the price of each item and finally appending the result to a list box in dollar format.

Product 1 is $3.99 ea. and there are 5 products total.
Product 2 is $1.40 ea. etc. etc.

The first radio button is named RdbProduct1 and the Text for it is Product 1

I have this block of code. C# did not find any syntax errors, but the result is not being appended to the list box. Any help with this is appreciated, thank you.

```
private void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Declare quantity variable convertted from Quantity text box
        decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(TxtQuanity.Text);

        //Determine Product price using a Switch 
        //Calculate total sale by multiplying product price by quantity
        //append result to list box
        RadioButton radioBtn = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                   .Where(x => x.Checked).FirstOrDefault();

        if (radioBtn != null)
        {
            switch (radioBtn.Name)
            {
                case "Product 1":
                    decimal cost = 3.99m;
                    decimal subtotal = quantity * cost;
                    LstSuccess.Items.Add (subtotal.ToString("c"));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger to be sure it hits the `Items.Add` line and inspect variables.  Use plenty of breakpoints if need be.  One day my wrists will be broken and I'll be using your code.

Comment: I'm thinking it is maybe not grabbing the decimal quantity variable from the first line due to indentation error, going to check that!

Comment: Yeah, just step through the method.  You'll find it.

Comment: Using the debugging it is saying my Radio Button 1 when checked is null and the switch code will only execute if the button is not null. Any ideas how to fix that? Neverminnd, that is not corrected, Radio button does say checked is true when I step through. It is not stepping through the Switch code for some reason though.

Comment: Sure I'll give you some hints.  `FirstOrDefault()` will return null if there are no items.  If you used `First()` an exception would be thrown.  You can break apart that LINQ, or inspect the radio buttons in the debugger.  Also break and inspect `radioBtn.Name`.  That would cause your switch to fall through.

Comment: Last hint, you should see while debugging that `Name` is probably not what you expect, or want.

Comment: Ugh this is frustrating haha. When I remove the .Name I get an error cannot implicitly convert type string to windows.forms.radiobutton

Comment: Look at the designer/code.  Where did you use "Product 1"?  Because I know it's not Name.  Why?  Name is the name of the control, not the displayed text.  You can work it out given all this.

Comment: The name of the control is RdbProduct1 If I use that I still get the same implicit conversion error though.

Comment: You gave me enough information to give you the answer without even seeing the rest of the code.  Sure I could post it, but then what do you learn?  Debugging code is an essential part of understanding code.

Comment: I got it working finally Wohoooo! I was using the Radio Button Text instead of the Radio Button Name in the switch statement so it wasn't stepping through. It is working! Just have to sum the list box now!

Comment: Is it acceptable to post a full working program here and ask for improvement suggestions and other features to add or skills to practice with the program?

Comment: That's best for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), unless you have a very specific objective answer you're looking for.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. I'm an impatient type of person, and I just want to learn everything about programming as fast as I possibly can and go into developing major applications and software, but I need to understand that I have been only doing this for about 6 months and it is a lifelong career of learning and I still have a lot of growing and skills to learn.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the comments of the OP getting to the correct answer:

Solution is changing

```
switch (radioBtn.Name)
```

To

```
switch (radioBtn.Text)
```

`Name` is the name of the `Control`.  `Text` is (in this case) what is displayed.